# Will files in my D drive be erased when installing Ubuntu alongside Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, installation

I am about to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 on a Thinkpad.

Windows resides in my C drive and I have my files in D. C and D happen to be two separate hard disks on my laptop, one stays in the normal hard disk slot, and the other in the DVD slot.

I found myself in front of this window and I am not sure whether this will erase my files in D if I press "Install now":

[image]

D is a 750GB hard disk with 573.3 GB free space. The rest is occupied by my files.

I suppose if I carry on with the installation, existing files shouldn't be deleted, but the picture seems like it will split the drive into two new partitions whipping out any existing file that is in it.

Do you think I can safely continue with the installation keeping existing files in D?

Comment: Most of the time files will be safe, but do you want to risk something going wrong? Back up important files before installing any OS.

Comment: @Moab Important files are on Dropbox. There are also other files, but it's not worth the effort to back up them. I also want to understand the logic behind this.

Comment: Files on another partition or hdd will only be affected if you choose that partition or hdd when you install an OS.

Comment: @Ramhound in my case I am choosing that partition (i.e. D)  where my files are located to install Ubuntu. So, that means files will be erased?

Comment: Yes; of course it will, don't choose that partition

Comment: @Ramhound it eventually didn't. Files are still there and Ubuntu created a partition itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be fine. Ubuntu installer is smart enough to know where your files are and avoid these sectors. I would recommend you to defrag your HDD before installing Ubuntu to  minimize the risk.
 Honestly, Ubuntu doesn't need that much space. In my school when we install Ubuntu alongside Windows XP we usually give Ubuntu about 40GB (half of the available disk space). I personally installed Xubuntu on my SSD and gave it only 20GB (8 for swap and 12 for the system). It worked without any problems.

Comment: Thanks, the installation went smoothly and files are still there. Wait... you have a reputation of 1 point and "killer" in your username? I was lucky this time :)

Comment: Glad I could help.